# debian testing / stretch resetting /etc/resolf.conf

Tags: debian

i know there is already a post about this topic here:
[/etc/resolv.conf keeps resetting itself](https://serverfault.com/questions/380073/etc-resolv-conf-keeps-resetting-itself)

but i already checked that
network-manager
dhclient
resolvconf

are not installed on this server system.

could dnsmasq be responsible for changing the resolf.conf file? but that wouldnt make much sense since it reads its "upstream" dns servers from it...or does it not?

my /etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.178.215
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.178.1
```

what else would change that file...and why?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/320716/find-out-which-process-is-changing-a-file/320718#320718

Comment: auditctl is a very nice tool, please add your comment as answer so i can accept it

Comment: We'll just close this a dupe and you can upvote my answer there.